# How do I use https.request to perform a get request?

Tags: node.js, https, get-request

I've been trying to use https.request() to do a perform a get request, but I don't know how I would it. '

The current code I have is

```
 const url="https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+query+"&appid="+apiKey+"&units="+unit;
https.get(url,function(response){
```

However I would like to use https.request because I am trying to understand the concept, and the code I got so far is

```
        var options={
      method: "GET",
      hostname:"api.openweathermap.org",
      path: "/data/2.5/weather?q="+query+"&appid="+apiKey+"&units="+unit,
      auth: "Eric:"+apikey
    }
  https.request(options,function(response){
```

I don't know why the http basic authentication did't work as the query string, I would like to learn about the differences. Thank you!

Comment: If your site expects the apikey to be in the query string, then that's where you have to put it, you can't put it in the `auth` field as that's a different kind of auth.

Comment: The "auth" field in `https.request()` uses [basic auth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).  You would have to see if your service supports basic auth.

Comment: oh, so if a api provider wants me to use the query string, i would have to use the query string. For instance, the openweather API wants me to use the query string , i cannot use the https basic authentication to pass the api keys. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  There are a number of different types of authentication.  You have to use the one that your service is expecting.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I was wondering if it doesn't matter what kind of authentication I use. Thank you for letting me know!